# Haunt #9 More than one traitor?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

BAHOTH: In haunt 9 you roll the dice at the beginning of your turn. If you roll less than 4 you lose one sanity. If you lose all of your sanity do you become the traitor if there is already a traitor? Can there be more than one traitor in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there can be more than on traitor in Haunt #9.

Although most haunt scenarios involve a single traitor with everyone else being heroes, there is no general rule in Betrayal at House on the Hill that says this must be the case. There is no reason a haunt can't have more than 1 traitor; or no traitors.

So you simply follow the text in the haunt instructions literally:

> If you fail the Sanity roll, and you’re in the
> Ballroom, you become insane. You are now a
> traitor. (Read this haunt in the Traitor’s Tome.)

> If you fail this roll in another room, you take 1
> Sanity damage instead. If your Sanity is reduced
> to the skull symbol, you don’t die; instead, you
> become a traitor (and must read this haunt in
> the Traitor’s Tome).

Note also that it says "**a** traitor" as opposed to "**the** traitor".